# Why the appbar openes among different pages in flipview?

Tags: c#, xaml, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime, appbar

I am using FlipView control for flipping through various pages i.e. *.XAML pages. I am using `ObservableCollection` of `Page` class. Now one page among those pages contains AppBar, but that AppBar can be open in any other XAML page from collection also. How can I prevent the opening of AppBar in all pages ?

Easy Explanation:- I have four XAML pages.

(1) MainPage.xaml (Contains only FlipView and ObservableCollection of Page class)

(2) PageWithAppBar.xaml (AppBar is in this page)

(3) PageWithoutAppBar.xaml

(4) PageWithoutAppBar2.xaml

Now through flipview, when I flip on **PageWithoutAppBar.xaml** or **PageWithoutAppBar2.xaml** and press right click then **AppBar** of **PageWithAppBar.xaml** become visible so I don't want that thing, how can I prevent that ?

What I have tried till now ?

I have created function to check in which page the AppBar should be visible.
I tried to set

`Visibility = Collapsed`,

`IsOpen = false`,

`this.BottomAppBar = null`,

`IsEnable = false`

then also it appears

Comment: Where is the actual AppBar defined? In MainPage.xaml?

Comment: Bottom AppBar is defined in PageWithAppBar.xaml

Comment: Have you tried IsSticky = false on the AppBar where it is defined?

Comment: Ok, posting some XAML and code-behind might help. Starting with MainPage.xaml, PageWithAppBar.xaml and PageWithoutAppBar.xaml :)

Comment: If nothing works, you could just hide the AppBar using IsOpen = false on PageWithAppBar.xaml before you navigate away from it.

Comment: here is code, http://codepad.org/s2eDZDEO
no code behind.
u can see appbar is only in Page 1 but it's visible in all the pages

Comment: So, what is in the SelectionChanged="FlipView_SelectionChanged_1" Loaded="flipview_Loaded_1" ?

Comment: those events just contain Debug.WriteLine(flipview.SelectedIndex)

Comment: I've just tried this out - it looks like the Page.BottomAppBar applies to the main container page - regardless of where it is declared.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the Page.BottomAppBar applies to the main container page - regardless of where it is declared. Given this, I'm not sure it is a good idea to use AppBars this way.

Perhaps you may want to create your own control that behaves like an appbar and make it work the way you want? Have a look at :[WinRT XAML Toolkit on Codeplex](http://winrtxamltoolkit.codeplex.com/) . There is a **CustomAppBar** control in there, which might work for you.